# How to rank the values across multiple columns per row

Tags: python, pandas, rank

I have a dataframe with 4 columns as follows:

```
               index 1   index 2    index 3      index 4
date                                                   
2023-07-14     0.0585     0.0775    -0.0289      0.0069
2023-07-17     0.0585     0.0750    -0.0300      0.0065
2023-07-18     0.0590     0.0729    -0.0311      0.0065
2023-07-19     0.0599     0.0711    -0.0309      0.0067
2023-07-20     0.0803     0.0689    -0.0309      0.0071
2023-07-21     0.0613     0.0677    0.0989       0.0083
```

I want to create a two new columns, 'rank 1', and 'rank 2' respectively to identify the indexes with the largest value and second largest value per each row, like below:

```
               index 1   index 2    index 3      index 4   Rank 1    rank 2 
date                                                   
2023-07-14     0.0585     0.0775    -0.0289      0.0069    index 2    index 1
2023-07-17     0.0585     0.0750    -0.0300      0.0065    index 2    index 1
2023-07-18     0.0590     0.0729    -0.0311      0.0065    index 2    index 1
2023-07-19     0.0599     0.0711    -0.0309      0.0067    index 2    index 1
2023-07-20     0.0803     0.0689    -0.0309      0.0071    index 1    index 2
2023-07-21     0.0613     0.0677     0.0989      0.0083    index 3    index 2
```

I learnt of the df.rank function but it appears that it only enables ranking values by columns, not by row.

Answer (score 0):

Use [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy)'s [`argpartition`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html), which will be the most efficient approach:

```
import numpy as np

N = 2
cols = df.columns.to_numpy()
df[[f'Rank {x+1}' for x in range(N)]] = cols[np.argpartition(df.to_numpy(),
                                                             -N)[:, :-N-1:-1]]
```

Output:

```
            index 1  index 2  index 3  index 4   Rank 1   Rank 2
date                                                            
2023-07-14   0.0585   0.0775  -0.0289   0.0069  index 2  index 1
2023-07-17   0.0585   0.0750  -0.0300   0.0065  index 2  index 1
2023-07-18   0.0590   0.0729  -0.0311   0.0065  index 2  index 1
2023-07-19   0.0599   0.0711  -0.0309   0.0067  index 2  index 1
2023-07-20   0.0803   0.0689  -0.0309   0.0071  index 1  index 2
2023-07-21   0.0613   0.0677   0.0989   0.0083  index 3  index 2
```

For a pure pandas approach (but much less efficient), [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html), filter and reshape with a [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
N = 2

out = df.join(df.stack().sort_values(ascending=False)
   .reset_index(-1)[['level_1']]
   .groupby(level=0).head(N)
   .assign(col=lambda d: 'Rank '+d.groupby(level=0).cumcount().add(1).astype(str))
   .pivot(columns='col', values='level_1')
)
```

Comment: Thank you for keep helping me solve such issues. I am struggling to understand the role and reason of 1) argpartition and also two arguments last of which has two semi-colon range) for the code section of below:

 cols[np.argpartition(df.to_numpy(),-N)[:, :-N-1:-1]]

Comment: @manwong0606 `argpartition` performs a partition, which is similar to a partial sort algorithm. In summary it guarantees that the `N` lowest/highest items (depending on the sign of `N`) will be at the correct position, the others (which we do not care about) won't necessarily be. The output of `argpartition` is thus similar to a that or a sorted array and we slice the `N` lowest/highest items of interest.

Comment: If this makes it easier to understand assuming `[0, 2, 5, 6, 1, 4, 3]` and wanting to get the top 2. If you sort `np.sort([0, 2, 5, 6, 1, 4, 3])` -> `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` and take the last 2 `np.sort([0, 2, 5, 6, 1, 4, 3])[-2:]` you get the two maxes `[5, 6]`. `argpartition` does the same thing but more efficiently and only the last 2 values are guaranteed to be in order `np.partition([0, 2, 5, 6, 1, 4, 3], -2)` -> `[2, 0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6]`.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done (upon further investigation) via a combination of apply and lambda functions:

```
    df['rank1']=df.T.apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(1).idxmin())
    df['rank2']=df.T.apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(2).idxmin())
```

Comment: This is however less efficient than `argpartition` since you'll have to read twice the full dataframe. Imagine a generalization to the to `N` largest, that would be unpractical.